# Listen for other components events

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am developing a component that act as an application taskbar.

Currently, I have a class `App` (that's not the fully qualified class name)  that extends `Ext.window.Window` which on `init` it creates a `button` with reference to itself and renders it to the taskbar. But I don't think this is the application's responsibility to add itself to the taskbar, but rather it is the taskbar's responsibility to listen for applications initialization and create a reference to them in it.

So, in the taskbar's `ViewController` I need to capture all the `render` events fired by any `App` instance. I can't find a way to do that in the documentation.

How can I do it? Or is there a better way of doing it?

ExtJS 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Define an Ext.app.EventDomain to monitor Ext.window.Window events.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.app.domain.Taskbar', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.EventDomain',
    singleton: true,
    requires: [
        'Ext.window.Window'
    ],
    // catalog the domain in the Ext.app.EventDomain.instances map
    type: 'taskbar',
    idProperty: 'id',
    constructor: function() {
        this.callParent();
        this.monitor( Ext.window.Window );
    }
})
```

Define a controller to listen for the window render event.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Taskbar', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires : [
        'MyApp.app.domain.Taskbar'
    ],
    init: function() {
        this.listen({
            taskbar: {
                // wildcard selector to match any window
                '*':{
                    render: function(window, eOpts){ 
                        console.log('render window: ' + window.id); 
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
})
```